# browser_cookie3 only able to take cookies from Firefox, Brave, and Opera GX and no other browser

Tags: python, cookies, browser

Using the exact same code, all I changed was the firefox to chrome on the second line, and the code kept giving me:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

My code:

```
try:
    cookies = browser_cookie3.firefox(domain_name='domain')
    for cookie in cookies:
        if cookie.name == 'cookie':
            data.append(cookie.value)
            return data
except:
    pass
```

I tried browser_cookie3.load() -- similar results

I searched up fixes for my error -- nothing worked

I searched up the documentation -- I followed everything properly and no change.

Does anyone have a solution?